# Using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

What is wrong with this regexp? I need it to make $name to be letter-number only. Now it doens't seem to work at all.

```
 if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]$/",$name)) {
  $e[]="name must contain only letters or numbers";
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a quantifier otherwise it will only allow one character. For example, to require that there must be one or more characters use `+`:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression does only describe one single character. Either use a [quantifier](http://php.net/regexp.reference.repetition) like `+` to allow that `[A-Za-z0-9]` is being repeated one or more times:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/",$name))
```

Or you can inverse your expression and look for characters that are not alphanumeric (`[^A-Za-z0-9]` is the complement of `[A-Za-z0-9]`):

```
if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/",$name))
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to look at other functions which will do what you want without the overhead of regexes. In this case, you could use [`ctype_alnum`](http://php.net/ctype_alnum).

Answer (score 1):

When you don't exactly know what your expression does, sometimes it helps to test it with a tool. You could try maybe Regex Coach: http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/ :)