# Regex JQUERY Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

need some help with regex and Jquery.

```
function cbprValidateUser(username){
    var reg = /^[a-zA-Z'.,-]$/;
    return (reg.test(username));
}
```

I want to use letters & numbers, no punctuation or spaces

Im rather lost

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938208/using-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is wrong. If you want only numbers and letter, use this: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*`

In your case:

```
function cbprValidateUser(username){
    var username = username || '';
    var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
    if (reg.test(username)){
        return true; }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Btw. this code is pure JavaScript ( no jQuery). 
Cheers